# The three elevator problem

Tags: algorithms

There are three elevators in a building that has twelve floors. Find an algorithm that needs to find the best possible way for the elevators to stop at any particular floor considering the traffic waiting for the lift on that floor. Consider the following constraints:

1. there can be any number of people that need to use the lift at any given time
2. these people can be on any floor at any time (they do not particularly start at the ground floor)
3. there is no way of finding the accurate number of people waiting for the elevators on any floor
4. there are two buttons next to each of the elevators, for calling the lift up and down

This is just an actual problem I am facing. The building I live in has three elevators and I think its code is bad. Put thoughts, interesting changes to the problem itself and of course creative solutions. Thank you ;)

Comment: How do you define "the best possible way"? Please clarify your question.

Comment: done, i have edited the problem. it is- the best possible way for the elevators to stop at any floor

Comment: "the best possible way" is not well-defined. Please provide a formal description of the input to the algorithm, of what constitutes a feasible solution, of the measure used to evaluate the quality of a solution.

Comment: @Steven Defining the problem is actually the hard part. The rest is easy :-)

Comment: This is fairly close to a duplicate of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/96278

Answer (score 0):

For a precise problem statement, first describe how a “standard” elevator setup works. Human users are supposed to know how it works and do things to get where they want to get.

There are lifts, floors, and a scheduler. Lifts are in the “up”, “down” or “idle” mode. They are standing still or they are moving. When standing still the door will be opened until it is safe to close. When moving there is a destination where to stop, and the next floor where it can stop. The lift will go there, stop, and open the door.

Each lift has buttons for each floor that the users press; each sets a destination. There may be another destination set by the scheduler. In up mode, the elevator goes up to the next destination upwards and stops there, then forgets that target. It stays in up mode until it has stopped, opened and closed the door, and there is no higher destination; similar in down mode.

On each floor, there are buttons to call a lift to go up, or to go down. There are indicators outside each lift showing whether a lift in “up” mode is going to stop on the floor, or a lift in “down” mode is going to stop. Pressing th up/down button indicates that at least one person wants to go up or down. This stays active until a lift going in the right direction stops. If people do not all fit then they need to be clever enough to wait until the lift leaves and press the button again once the lift is gone.

The scheduler gets all the state. All that it can do is to set an external destination for each lift (or none).

So you describe the lift state: Up, down, or idle. Moving to destination, next possible stop, stopped with door opened, stopped with door closed again. List of internal targets. Optional external targets. The floor state: Someone wants up or not. Someone wants down or not. Outside each lift: Lift will stop or is stopped to go up, same for down.

Most of the actions are forced. What is not forced is the external destination that the scheduler can set, that’s what you are optimising. The scheduler sets external destinations for the lifts if anyone wants to go up or down. Since it knows all the state it may just call the lift that will arrive first going in the right direction.

Rules for setting external destination: The scheduler cannot change the direction of a lift. So if someone wants up, you can call a list that is idle or that goes up and isn’t past this floor. You can estimate the time: The time a lift travels, plus time for each stop. The cost is a function of the waiting time, plus a function of lift wear and tear.

Note that the scheduler can change its decision, for example if a lift stayed on some floor for a very long time, or users in the lift add stops. But it is very bad style to announce that a lift is coming, and then clearing it.

Now if you wanted advice how to solve the optimisation problem: No. The difficult part is stating the problem. You need to do that very, very, very carefully. Then at any point in time, the scheduler makes three decisions which lift to send to which floor or whether not to send it anywhere. This decision is updated every time something happens, and every second (in case guesses about timing were wrong). That part is easy.